# How to disable overlay scrollbar hiding behavior

Tags: 11.10, overlay-scrollbars

If I move mouse cursor on the scrollbar and don't move it then scrollbar just hides after few seconds. How can I disable such behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Here I did this a while back. This it what I used

```
sudo su
echo "export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0" > /etc/X11/Xsession.d/80overlayscrollbars
```

now logout & login

Answer (score 0):

There are no apparent settings that are easily accessible through the gconf-editor or Ubuntu-tweak. I did find a manpage referring to the QScrollBar values and settings. I would suppose they can be tweaked/hacked in some manner.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man3/qscrollbar.3qt.html